# white clipping mask is still visible when saving as png

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, png

When I try to save my logo in Illustrator as PNG, you can see the white rectangles.
If I do this in Photoshop and use clipping mask, and try to save it, you don't see the white rectangle.
How can I do the same trick in Illustrator?[image]

(The white on the left and right isn't visible on here because the background is also white.)

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator's PNG export does not convert white objects as transparent. If you wish for the area covered by the white rectangles to be transparent in your PNG, you have cut the rectangles away from the letters. There are a few ways to do this. The easiest and cleanest way would be to select all of the letters in "Virtual" and select Object>Compound Path>Make. Then select all of the white rectangles and make them a compound path as well. Then, with the white rectangles and "Virtual" selected, select "Minus Front" from the Pathfinder pallet. Good luck!